# Using removeLayer of Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

See the Leaflet tutorial for adding a layer control to your map:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = "Scripts/images";

var mapUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var secondMap = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var littleton = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
denver = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
aurora = L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
golden = L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.');

var cities = L.layerGroup([littleton, denver, aurora, golden]);

var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mapUrl, { id: mapUrl }),
streets = L.tileLayer(secondMap, { id: secondMap });

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [grayscale, cities]
});

var baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

How do I use the removeLayer function to remove the "GrayScale" map from the control using a map.on('click') event?

The code would be:

```
map.on('click', function(){
    //remove GrayScale
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to remove the grayscale map from the start just delete:

```
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
```

From

```
var baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets
};
```

If you want to remove the layer on a click you call it as a method on the map object.
Like so:

```
map.removeLayer(grayscale)
```

To remove it from the control you first have to assign the control to a variable.
Change this:

```
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

To this:

```
lcontrol = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Then you can call:

```
lcontrol.removeLayer(grayscale)
```

..to remove it from the control.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a layer to `L.control`, you add an object by reference.
Instead of remove the layer, you can modify the object :

```js
let baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets
};
```

```js
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

```js
baseMaps = {
    "Streets": streets
};
```

I did this with overlayMaps. Each time I uploaded new markers, the old ones still stayed in overlay. And I realized I made an array from markers and pushed new ones in it.
So I reset my array before upload : `overlayMarkers.length = 0` and it works !