# Remove Leaflet layer at zoom level

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I can't remove a Leaflet layer from my map. I have referenced a lot of other SO threads about this very subject. Even so, `removeLayer()` refuses to work. `addLayer()` works just fine.

Threads I've visited (among others):

[leaflet-layers-on-different-zoom-levels-how](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182628/leaflet-layers-on-different-zoom-levels-how)

[leaflet-how-do-you-use-removelayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/leaflet-how-do-you-use-removelayer)

[function-with-map-addlayer-and-map-removelayer-not-working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371901/function-with-map-addlayer-and-map-removelayer-not-working)

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {

    const npsBoundaries = L.esri.featureLayer({
        url: 'https://services1.arcgis.com/fBc8EJBxQRMcHlei/ArcGIS/rest/services/National_Park_Service_Boundaries/FeatureServer/0',
        style: function(feature) {
            return { color: 'gray' };
        }
    });

    if (map.getZoom() > 6.5) {
        map.addLayer(npsBoundaries);      // <-- this works
    } else if (map.getZoom() <= 6.5) {
        map.removeLayer(npsBoundaries).   // <-- why doesn't this work?
    }
```

If it helps, I am using Leaflet v1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a condition to `if` statement whether the layer exists. If you don't do this, you will add one more layer for each `'zoomend'`.

Use this way:

```
const npsBoundaries = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://services1.arcgis.com/fBc8EJBxQRMcHlei/ArcGIS/rest/services/National_Park_Service_Boundaries/FeatureServer/0',
    style: function (feature) {
        return { color: 'gray' };
    }
});

map.on('zoomend',
    function () {
        if (map.getZoom() > 6.5 && !map.hasLayer(npsBoundaries)) {
            map.addLayer(npsBoundaries);
        }
        if (map.getZoom() <= 6.5 && map.hasLayer(npsBoundaries)) {
            map.removeLayer(npsBoundaries)
        }
    }
);
```